# Proof of De la Vallée-Poussin's Test

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

Here's what I'm trying to prove.

Suppose that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $J = [c,+\infty)$. Let $f: A \times J \to \mathbb{R}^p$ be continuous and suppose that there exists a function $g: J \to [0,+\infty)$ such that:

$$\forall (x,t) \in A \times J: \|f(x,t)\| \leq g(t)$$

Suppose that $\int_{c}^{\infty} g(t) \ dt$ is convergent. Then, $\int_{c}^{\infty} f(x,t) \, dt$ is uniformly convergent for $x \in A$.

Here's the definition of uniform convergence (I'm pretty sure that this is really just an extension of the definition of improper integrals on the real line).

Again, let $f$ be as given above. Then, define $F(x) = \int_{c}^{\infty} f(x,t) \, dt$. We say that $f$ is uniformly convergent for $x \in A$ iff:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists D > c: x \in A \land d \geq D \implies \left\| F(x)-\int_{c}^{d} f(x,t) \right\| < \epsilon$$

---

Proof Attempt:

Observe that for any fixed $x \in A$, we have:

$$\forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,p\}: |f_i(x,t)| \leq \left\|f(x,t)\right\| \leq g(t)$$

$$\implies \forall d > c: \int_{c}^{d} |f_i(x,t)| \ dt \leq \int_{c}^{d} g(t) \ dt$$

Then, since $\int_{c}^{d} g(t) \ dt$ converges as $d \to \infty$, it follows that $\int_{c}^{d} |f_i(x,t)| \ dt$ converges as $d \to \infty$ by comparison. Then, this implies that $\int_{c}^{\infty} f_i(x,t) \ dt$ converges and since the integral of each component function of $f$ converges, it follows that $\int_{c}^{\infty} f(x,t) \ dt$ converges. $\Box$

The thing that I'm somewhat worried about is if I'm missing something crucial over here. Like, I'm just wondering if I've overlooked something or if I would actually have to do a more formal argument using the definition directly. I'd appreciate it if someone could have a look at my working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

$$\int_c^d |f_i(x,t)| \, dt \leqslant\int_c^d g(t) \, dt,$$

and the fact that the integrand on the LHS is nonnegative, you can only conclude pointwise convergence, that is for each $x \in A$,

$$\lim_{d \to \infty} \int_c^d |f_i(x,t)| \, dt = \limsup_{d \to \infty}\int_c^d |f_i(x,t)| \, dt \leqslant \lim_{d \to \infty}\int_c^d g(t) \, dt$$

To prove uniform convergence, you need to show that

$$\lim_{d \to \infty} \sup_{X \in A}\left|\int_d^\infty f_i(x,t) \, dt \right| = 0$$

We have,

$$\left|\int_d^R f_i(x,t) \, dt \right| \leqslant\int_d^R |f_i(x,t)| \, dt \leqslant\int_d^R g(t) \, dt \leqslant \int_d^\infty g(t) \, dt$$

Taking the limit as $R \to \infty$ we get

$$\left|\int_d^\infty f_i(x,t) \, dt \right|\leqslant  \int_d^\infty g(t) \, dt, \\\sup_{x \in A}\left|\int_d^\infty f_i(x,t) \, dt \right|\leqslant  \int_d^\infty g(t) \, dt$$

Since the improper integral of $g$ converges, we get as desired

$$\lim_{d \to \infty}\sup_{x \in A}\left|\int_d^\infty f_i(x,t) \, dt \right|=\lim_{d \to \infty}  \int_d^\infty g(t) \, dt = 0$$

Comment: ... or equivalently prove that the uniform Cauchy criterion holds: $\left| \int_{d_1}^{d_2} f_i(x,t) \, dt\right| < \epsilon$ for all $d_2\geqslant d_1 > D(\epsilon)$ and all $x \in A$.

Comment: Oh wow alright, thank you so much! I haven't actually learnt about limsup and all that stuff (just didn't get to that in real analysis). It's a good excuse to just go and learn it then :D

Comment: Your sense that you had something missing was correct.  Uniform convergence is about showing the rate at which $\left|\int_d^\infty f(x,t) \, dt \right|$ converges to $0$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Yeap I was a little weirded out that it seemed that simple. I was afraid that I wasn't quite grasping what the definition was saying. 

Actually, hmm, I'm wondering if there's a way to get to the same result using just the given definition. I'll have a go at doing that while I read over your argument in more detail.

Comment: But if you want to avoid limsup, you just say $\left|\int_{d}^{\infty} f_i(x,t) \, dt \right| \leqslant  \int_{d}^{\infty} g(x,t) \, dt$. We can make the RHS less that $\epsilon$ by taking $d $ sufficiently large (independent of $x$) since the integral of $g$ converges and does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Alright nice, that sounds perfect. Once again, thank you so much :D